# Web API and Cancellation Token

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to have a Web API and Cancellation Token working together, but it doesn't seem to play nicely for some reason.

Here is my code for my Web API. It contains cancellation token properties, and methods

```
public class TokenCancellationApiController : ApiController
{
    private static CancellationTokenSource cTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    // Create a cancellation token from CancellationTokenSource
    private static CancellationToken cToken = cTokenSource.Token;
    // Create a task and pass the cancellation token

    [HttpGet]
    public string BeginLongProcess()
    {
        string returnMessage = "The running process has finished!";
        try
        {
            LongRunningFunc(cToken, 6);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException cancelEx)
        {
            returnMessage = "The running process has been cancelled.";
        }
        finally
        {
            cTokenSource.Dispose();
        }
        return returnMessage;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string CancelLongProcess()
    {
        // cancelling task
        cTokenSource.Cancel();
        return "Cancellation Requested";
    }

    private static void LongRunningFunc(CancellationToken token, int seconds)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Long running method");
        for (int j = 0; j < seconds; j++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cancellation observed.");
                throw new OperationCanceledException(token); // acknowledge cancellation
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done looping");
    }
}
```

And I have the below HTML code:

```
<script>
    function BeginLongProcess()
    {
        alert("Will now send AJAX request to start long 6 second process...");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/TokenCancellationApi/BeginLongProcess",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                console.error(err.Message)
            }
        });
    }
    function CancelLongProcess() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/TokenCancellationApi/CancelLongProcess",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                console.error(err.Message)
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<form id="aForm" runat="server">
    <p>
        <button type="button" onclick="BeginLongProcess()">Begin Long Process</button>
    </p>
    <p>
        <button type="button" onclick="CancelLongProcess()">Cancel Long Process</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

The Web API methods gets called fine.
When I click the button to begin the long process, and then hit cancel, I expected it to cancel the long process, and return an alert message telling me it was cancelled.

But that's not the case. Although there was a token cancel request, it doesn't seem to be registering, and the long process keeps on running until it is finished.

Can anyone please tell me why is this not working as I want it to?

Comment: You are checking the `CancellationToken` *outside* the tight loop which calls `Thread.Sleep`. This is never going to work. If you introduce `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` just after `Sleep` it will work (probably - not really sure of Web Api inner workings), but even if it does you're better off using async APIs which natively support `CancellationToken` (at the very least `Task.Delay`).

Comment: Updated code, to have it within the for loop, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your thread sleep is deterministic, as such thread won't wake up when you click Cancel. Also, check should be done during iteration if cancel was requested. As you have made the token source static, you can only run one long running call at a time. That is why you have to also check if one has already been kicked off or not before starting your long running process. Added necessary locks to ensure your instances are synchronized properly.

Modified your code a bit, but works as expected. Made it run for configured iterations to test easily. Also, increased sleep to 5 seconds. Change them as needed.

This will also work if you want to run long running method asynchronously. Uncomment the commented code in the begin method.

```
public class TokenCancellationApiController : ApiController
{
    private static object _lock = new object();
    public static string _lastError;

    // Static types will mean that you can only run 
    // one long running process at a time.
    // If more than 1 needs to run, you will have to 
    // make them instance variable and manage 
    // threading and lifecycle
    private static CancellationTokenSource cTokenSource;       
    private static CancellationToken cToken;

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/TokenCancellationApi/BeginLongProcess/{seconds}")]
    public string BeginLongProcess(int seconds)
    {
        //Lock and check if process has already started or not.
        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (null != cTokenSource)
            {
                return "A long running is already underway.";
            }
            cTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        }

        //if running asynchronously
        //var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => LongRunningFunc(cTokenSource.Token, seconds));
        //task.ContinueWith(Cleanup);
        //return "Long running process has started!";

        //if running synchronusly
        try
        {
            LongRunningFunc(cTokenSource.Token, seconds);            
        }
        catch(OperationCanceledException)
        {
            return "The running process has been cancelled";
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            _lastError = ex.Message;
            return ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            Cleanup(null);
        }
        return "Long running process has completed!";

    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string CancelLongProcess()
    {
        // cancelling task
        if (null != cTokenSource)
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (null != cTokenSource)
                {
                    cTokenSource.Cancel();
                }
                return "Cancellation Requested";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "Long running task already completed";
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string GetLastError()
    {
        return (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_lastError)) ? "No Error" : _lastError;
    }

    private static void Cleanup(Task task)
    {
        if (null != task && task.IsFaulted)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error encountered while running task");
            _lastError = task.Exception.GetBaseException().Message;
        }

        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (null != cTokenSource)
            {
                cTokenSource.Dispose();
            }
            cTokenSource = null;
        }
    }

    private static void LongRunningFunc(CancellationToken token, int seconds)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Long running method");
        int j = 0;

        //Long running loop should always check if cancellation requested.
        while(!token.IsCancellationRequested && j < seconds)            
        {
            //Wait on token instead of deterministic sleep
            //This way, thread will wakeup as soon as canellation
            //is requested even if sleep time hasn't elapsed.
            //Waiting 5 seconds
            token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(5000);
            j++;
        }

        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            throw new OperationCanceledException();
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Done looping");
    }
}
```

HTML part

```
<script>
    function BeginLongProcess()
    {
        alert("Will now send AJAX request to start long 6 second process...");
        var seconds = $("#seconds").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/TokenCancellationApi/BeginLongProcess/"+seconds,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                console.error(err.Message)
            }
        });
    }
    function CancelLongProcess() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/TokenCancellationApi/CancelLongProcess",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                console.error(err.Message)
            }
        });
    }

    function GetLastError() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/TokenCancellationApi/GetLastError",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                console.error(err.Message)
            }
        });
    }
    </script>


    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <p>
       Iterations: <input id="seconds" type="text" value="10" /> <br />
        <button type="button" onclick="BeginLongProcess()">Begin Long Process</button>
    </p>
    <p>
        <button type="button" onclick="CancelLongProcess()">Cancel Long Process</button>
    </p>

    <p>
        <button type="button" onclick="GetLastError()">Get Last Error</button>
    </p>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Does not seem to work, still the same similar issue. 
I realised it seems my "cTokenSource" variable is null each time I make a Web API request.
Perhaps it's doesn't persist my variable across requests?

Comment: My bad, looks like I didn't copy the HTML code properly, only got the C# code. It wasn't calling the "BeginLongProcess" method properly, so it didn't initialize the "cTokenSource" variable, hence why it was null...

Comment: Using static data in MVC controller is incorrect, the answer tries to make working originally flawed design.

Comment: Correct, I mentioned the issue with static in the comments section of the attached code. This answer doesn't attempt to provide ideal architecture, rather just solves op's issue with hints on how to make it better.

Comment: would it not be dangerous because of static? if that is static it might affect the other request that should not be cancelled imo

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/07/19/cancelling-long-running-queries-in-asp-net-mvc-and-web-api.aspx
you don’t need to create a separate action to cancel and share state between 2 actions using static objects(very bad style for multi user application)

You can just do

```
xhr.abort()
```

on a client.

Update: Any modern data access layer,such as Entity Framework,  should be able to pass your cancellation token and cancel long running queries when a request from the client is aborted.

Comment: This would only work to a point, but if you're fetching records from a db, this won't cut it.. the damage is already done, even though you cancelled the ajax request. If you send a cancellation token to an async service in the back, you can cancel that db data fetching service.

Comment: @sksallaj , from the linked above article: “ Both MVC and Web API will recognize the cancelled request and signal a cancellation to the async action method for that request... If the browser cancels the HTTP Request, MVC will set the CancellationToken to cancelled and Entity Framework will cancel the SQL query that was executing as part of that request.

Comment: Yes MVC would, but not through jquery ajax, the CancellationToken is only bound to MVC. I have done the xhr.abort with cancellations before, and the token doesn't set isCancellationRequested to true. In the above example, he uses jquery and uses a c# service to set the token.

Comment: @sksallaj From the same article “In a single page app, you will need to cancel HTTP requests yourself.  in jQuery all you need to do is call the abort() method on the XMLHttpRequest instance”, but also note the workaround for MVC 5 at the bottom of the article.

Comment: I read the article. Pulling my comments together, cancelling the HTTP requests myself using jquery isn't sufficient, as it doesn't cancel the token, it just cancel's the request.. so if I have an internal structure using DBCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync, or DBDataReader.NextResultAsync, for example, cancelling the HTTP request doesn't cancel that kind procedure.. only if you're using MVC can you send the CancellationToken. I'm only making the comments specifically to the OP as he wasn't using MVC nor MVC 5. That's why the article doesn't apply to his case.

Comment: @sksallaj Have you considered to use Entity Framework? As you are using low level DbCommand, you need to implement yourself the mechanism of cancelling data reading.

Comment: Yup, unfortunately I'm using EF Core, and at this point there is no way to retrieve a result set from a stored proc until the next iteration (which I think is still in progress), so I had to do that manually :-D